# VBA Click HoverMenu Link in IE, Without ID Tag

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, click

I just can't get VBA to successful click one link in a dropdown hover menu (there is no ID tag). To be specific I am using VBA to log in to a site and navigate to a certain page that returns information from a database.

Here is the HTML menu with the link:

```html
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/APBKIS/js/struts-menu/coolmenu4-config.js"></script>
  <div>
    <ul id="primary-nav" class="menuList">
      <li class="menubar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Service" target="_self">Service</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="menubar">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Reports" target="_self">Reports</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="declRetrieval?asType=AIR" title="Formal Entries" target="_self">FormalEntries</a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="declRetrieval?asType=BRIEF" title="InformalEntries" target="_self">InformalEntries</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menubar">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="UserData">UserData</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="CustProf!Approve" title="ChangeUserData">Change User Data</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
              <a href="CustProf!ChgPwd" title="ChangePassword">Change Password</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to click the InformalEntries item on the dropdown menu.

This is part of my current VBA code:

Sub ReportCall()

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim link As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://somesite.com"

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set html = IE.document
html.getElementById("usrId").Value = "usernameabc"
html.getElementById("usrPwd").Value = "passwordabc"

'Click the "submit" button
html.getElementById("Image15").Click

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'html.getElementById("myThis").Click
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
    If link.innerHTML = "InformalEntries" Then
        link.Click
    End If
Next link
```

I am stuck trying to get past the dropdown menu (InformalEntries), nothing happens, no errors are returned in excel either.

N.B. the link when clicked manually does not navigate to a new webpage. I think it is calling a javascript function that then uses php to return the data/information onto the current page. Looking through the html code I think this is the function being called on click:

```js
function viewPerm(actionUrl) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: actionUrl,
    data: null,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(divDetail) {
      ScreenConvert();
      ShowDialog(divDetail, 700, 500);
    },
    error: function(req, status, error) {}
  });
}
/*]]>*/
<
/script>
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions and help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the website publicly available?  Can you post a URL?  Your loop with doevents does not guarentee that the html is ready.  To test this try and load the page manually  and then only run your cope from this point -  html.getElementsByTagName("a")

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't post the URL as it is not public. It requires a username and password. I tried adding a 10 second wait timer before firing the click action, nothing happens. I also tried your suggestion of waiting for the page to load manually, but again nothing happens. Just to clarify, the previous link clicks (which work OK) actually load and navigate to a new page. However, this link, where I am getting stuck (link.innerHTML = "InformalEntries") does not load a new page when clicked - it calls a function and fetches the report/data on to the current page.

Comment: Wait timer will not work as it's on the same thread

Comment: To be clear other than getting an existing NOT NEW IE your code starts with Set ElementCol ....

Comment: Correct - it runs fine up to Set ElementCol.

Comment: Great so now we want to check whether the HTMLDocument is really ready or that we need to work on your code. Now either open the website manually and login manually and then get that IE that is already open or maybe move your new IE and visible and navigate only to a new button event, then manually login then use the code from Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a").  The point is to make sure that the htmldocument is fully loaded and ready for the click event, or whether something else needs to happen.

Comment: The HTMLDocument is ready, but nothing is happening.

Comment: N.B. I tested it on other links on the same page and it does click. However, it just won't click "InformalEntries" or anything else in the dropdown menu (html code provided in original question).

Comment: The ready state of a HTMLDocument can be complete and elements are being added by some script. Have you tried my suggestion of making sure the page is fully loaded manually and then running your code? So you have tried "formal entries" and it works?

Comment: Correct, I tried your suggestion of making sure the page is fully loaded and then manually running the code. But, it didn't work.

Comment: No it does not work on "formal entries", that link is also in the dropdown menu - as mentioned it won't click any of the links in the dropdown menu. It does however work on other links that are not in the dropdown menu. For example, it works OK on this link (not part of the dropdown menu) <td class="menubar" id="primary-nav"><a title="Log Out" href="/APISSO/Logout.shtml">Logout</a></td>

Comment: without being able to test I am pretty much guessing.  Have you tried clicking the parent of the link i.e. the LI element? Otherwise you are going to have to simulate a mouseover or maybe call the script that would be fired from a click.  Neither of these will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
 Set html = IE.document
```

it's only valid until you trigger a navigation to another page: once the page reloads, your reference to the previous document is no good, and you need to reset it by running that line again.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the comment. I tried adding the reference, but still nothing happening, it just won't click. In the end I just removed the reference.